# Issue with top table view cell being hidden or having spacing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've had some issues with my table view and the top cell. I'm using grouped Prototype Cells, and I've come across an issue with the spacing between the top bar and the first cell. As I've seen on other posts, I tried using 'adjust scroll insets' however, this created another problem, with the cell being hidden underneath the navigation bar. When I try changing the translucency of the navigation bar, the spacing returns. I've got some links to the images below.

[image: Cell not hidden, but spacing]

[image: Cell hidden]

Comment: Can you share us your code.

Comment: I've just used the IB for this

Answer (score 0):

When you use grouped cell, it's make space automatically in the header section. Try that;

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
        return 5.0;
    return 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because that you're using Grouped Style. people use this style to add their header for each group.

You should change the style to plain.

In xib, you should change the `Style` to `Plain`

[image]

Or do this programmaticlly when init the UITableView

```
UITableView *myTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero 
                                            style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Comment: Thanks ronan, but I specifically wanted to use a grouped table view here.

Comment: Why do you have to use Grouped style while you wanna try to hide the header.

Comment: you can check the `Setting` App, they got header space too. It the normal way to use Grouped style

Comment: I'm using prototype cells and I want to just add 1 section, for the header, but there doesn't seem to be an option for it

Comment: Then just use `Plain` style, its default setting is one group. `numberOfSection` you return 1.

Comment: and specify the height of the UITableView